# Why does z-index not work?

Tags: html, css, z-index

So if I understand `z-index` correctly, it would be perfect in this situation:

[image]

I want to place the bottom image (the tag/card) below the div above it. So you can't see the sharp edges. How do I do this?

```
z-index:-1 // on the image tag/card
```

or

```
z-index:100 // on the div above
```

doesn't work either. Neither does a combination of anything like this. How come?

Comment: Sometime we make mistake of appying position value other than `static` only to one element. We should ensure that we're applying the position property to all the elements being stacked on the basis of z-index else it doesn't work.

Comment: Some useful hints on this linked other question, which could be of use. You would have to share the elements and all their actual styles for somebody to advice about if this is the case more specifically than RBT did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217407/css-negative-z-index-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 679, accepted):

The [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) property only works on elements with a [`position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) value other than `static` (e.g. `position: absolute;`, `position: relative;`, `position: fixed` or `position: sticky`).

Note that `position: sticky;` is prefixed in Safari 7.1-12 and not available on many browsers before 2016.

Comment: [It is also depending on other factors to create `Stacking Context`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: adding to this answer, chrome and likely other browsers as of this writing require that you explicitly state `position: relative` for z-index to work, despite elements behaving in other relative ways by default

Comment: `static` elements are *static* and can't move around in `x, y or z planes`.  They can't move in `x plane (left or right)` or `y plane (top or bottom)` like when we work with `position: absolute`.  And nor can they move in the `z plane i.e. with z-index`.

Comment: are you aware of any issues with using `z-index` in a grid element??

Comment: `sticky` is now supported by all modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-sticky

Comment: In my case, it was due to the fixed element not having a background color, it seemed like it was not overlaying, but in reality it was, but only with the foreground colors.

Answer (score 148):

If you set position to other value than `static` but your element's `z-index` still doesn't seem to work, it may be that some parent element has `z-index` set.

The stacking contexts have hierarchy, and each stacking context is considered in the stacking order of the parent's stacking context.

So with following html

```css
div { border: 2px solid #000; width: 100px; height: 30px; margin: 10px; position: relative; background-color: #FFF; }
#el3 { background-color: #F0F; width: 100px; height: 60px; top: -50px; }
```

```html
<div id="el1" style="z-index: 5"></div>
<div id="el2" style="z-index: 3">
  <div id="el3" style="z-index: 8"></div>
</div>
```

no matter how big the `z-index` of `el3` will be set, it will always be under `el1` because it's parent has lower stacking context. You can imagine stacking order as levels where stacking order of `el3` is actually **3.8** which is lower than **5**.

If you want to check stacking contexts of parent elements, you can use this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("#yourElement"); // or use $0 in chrome;
do {
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    console.log(styles.zIndex, el);
} while(el.parentElement && (el = el.parentElement));
```

[There is a great article about stacking contexts on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: set proper z-index of parent elements.

Comment: Just for note: when your parent element has `position: sticky` and it does not have z-index then whatever z-index you set to its child elements it will not work, you have to set some z-index for parent element, maybe it's true for all position types: `sticky, relative, absolute` etc but it was `sticky` in my case.

Comment: All around great answer. Snippet was perfect for identifying the problem or quickly ruling out this solution.

Answer (score 46):

Your elements need to have a `position` attribute. (e.g. `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`) or `z-index` won't work.

Answer (score 31):

In many cases an element must be positioned for `z-index` to work.

Indeed, applying `position: relative` to the elements in the question would likely solve the problem (but there's not enough code provided to know for sure).

Actually, `position: fixed`, `position: absolute` and `position: sticky` will also enable `z-index`, but those values also change the layout. With `position: relative` the layout isn't disturbed.

Essentially, as long as the element isn't `position: static` (the default setting) it is considered positioned and `z-index` will work.

---

Many answers to *"Why isn't z-index working?"* questions assert that `z-index`  *only* works on positioned elements. As of CSS3, this is no longer true.

Elements that are [***flex items***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) or [***grid items***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) can use `z-index` even when `position` is `static`.

*From the specs:*

> [**4.3. Flex Item Z-Ordering**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting)
>
> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks, except that order-modified document order is used in place of raw 
>   document order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context even if `position` is `static`.
>
> [**5.4. Z-axis Ordering: the `z-index` property**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order)
>
> The painting order of grid items is exactly the same as inline blocks, except that order-modified document order is 
>   used in place of raw document order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context even if 
>   `position` is `static`.

Here's a demonstration of `z-index` working on non-positioned flex items: https://jsfiddle.net/m0wddwxs/

Comment: "Elements that are flex items or grid items can use z-index even when position is static." Yep, the spec essentially says to treat `position: static` the exact same as it would treat `position: relative` for flex and grid items due to the dynamic nature of those methods of layout. So I would perhaps say it's not that it's no longer true in CSS3 that an element needs to be positioned, but that CSS3 treats flex and grid items as if they were positioned, regardless. Just two ways of looking at the same thing, though, probably.

Comment: @TylerH we should pay attention to that part of the spec because we should *treat static the same as relative* only when dealing with z-index and not in general. You cannot for example shift a flex item using left/top/bottom/right unless you explicitely speficy `position:relative`. Descendants of flex items with absolute position will not consider the flex item as their containing block because the flex item is not positionned. (https://jsfiddle.net/0yo7utfL/2/)

Comment: i found a wierd "bug" with css. for some reason `overflow-y: scroll` prevents `overflow-x: visible` from working... [can you please take a look?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59538547/7543162)

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that this element you would like to control with z-index does not have a **parent with z-index property**, because element is in a **lower stacking context** due to its parent’s z-index level.

Here's an example:

```
<section class="content">            
    <div class="modal"></div>
</section>

<div class="side-tab"></div>

// CSS //
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

.side-tab {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

In the example above, the modal has a higher z-index than the content, although the content will appear on top of the modal because "**content**" is the parent with a z-index property.

Here's an article that explains 4 reasons why z-index might not work:
https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/

Answer (score 14):

Z-index needs these to work:

1. Position: relative, absolute, fixed, ..
2. Make sure that the parent element hasn't `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the overflow note! 
That was the issue in my case

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with `z-index` and fixed it by setting the background color like this:

```
 background-color: white;
```

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, look for syntax errors in your HTML. It's not intuitive, but I've seen it be the reason why `z-index` doesn't work.

The following code has invalid HTML syntax:

```
<div class="over"/>
<div class="under"/>
```

...(it's is invalid syntax because a div isn't a self closing tag).

CSS properties that were applied to these rogue HTML elements, such as `background-color: black`, `position: fixed`, `width: 150px`, and `top:150px`, were all working as expected. However, the `z-index: 2` property wasn't working under the exact same conditions.

Only when the invalid HTML was fixed did the `z-index` work correctly.

I'm not sure why `z-index` was pickier than the other CSS attributes, but maybe this answer can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from codercoder.com: In my code I have set my **Navbar's opacity to 0.9**.

Once you remove the `opacity` property from the Navbar's CSS, the `z-index` works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, in my case was the `backdrop-filter`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to transform interfering with z-index working, I'd also like to add that using the 'perspective' property can also stop z-index from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you have set legit `z-index` and `position` (`absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, `sticky`), and it still doesn't work as expected, the problem might be with `transform` or `opacity` rules on one of the element's parents, that could make them behave as if they had zero `z-index`. A solution is to set `z-index` explicitly on the parent block with such rules (along with `position`).

Here's the specs for the reference:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering

> **3. The Transform Rendering Model**
>
> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value
> other than none for the
> [transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform)
> property results in the creation of a stacking context.
> Implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent
> stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it
> were a positioned element with [z-index:
> 0](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#propdef-z-index). If an
> element with a transform is positioned, the z-index property applies
> as described in
> [[CSS2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#biblio-css2), except
> that
> [auto](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#valdef-z-index-auto) is
> treated as 0 since a new stacking context is always created.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparency

> **3.2. Transparency: the ‘opacity’ property**
>
> Since an element with opacity less than 1 is composited from a single
> offscreen image, content outside of it cannot be layered in z-order
> between pieces of content inside of it. For the same reason,
> implementations must create a new stacking context for any element
> with opacity less than 1. If an element with opacity less than 1 is
> not positioned, then it is painted on the same layer, within its
> parent stacking context, as positioned elements with stack level 0. If
> an element with opacity less than 1 is positioned, the '`z-index`'
> property applies as described in
> [[CSS21]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#ref-CSS21), except that
> if the used value is '`auto`' then the element behaves exactly as if
> it were '`0`'. See [section
> 9.9](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) and [Appendix E](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) of
> [[CSS21]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#ref-CSS21) for more
> information on stacking contexts. The rules in this paragraph do not
> apply to SVG elements, since SVG has its own [rendering
> model](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/render.html)
> ([[SVG11]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#ref-SVG11), Chapter 3).

Answer (score 0):

I had a select element inside a "card"

My card had this class applied:

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid var(--gray-200);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0/0.05));
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 4px 5px;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;     
}
```

I removed the filter property and that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

in my case the setting upper element to z-index: -1 helps.