# Why z-index is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="logo">
    <div id="left-block">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right-block">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu1</li>
        <li>Menu2</li>
        <li>Menu3</li>
        <li>Menu4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It shows a title at the top-left corner and a item menu at the top right using this CSS code:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

#left-block {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}

#right-block {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
}

ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0px;
}
```

The problem is when I have a long title as showed in this [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nNkKT/). The title overlaps the menu and z-index seems that is not working (I've put z-index everywhere without success). Why z-index is not working? Is because #logo is absolutely positioned? How to resolve this problem?

**NOTE**: I can't change this (`#logo {position:absolute}`) because other elements not showed in this simplified demo needs it.

Comment: `#right-block` is not positioned absolute or relative. See the docs: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index.

Comment: @FelixKling that is actually the right answer, if you post it i'll upvote it. `z-index` only works within the context of a relative/fixed or absolute position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does z-index not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manually set the `#right-block` position :

```
#right-block {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

z-index only woks on `absolute|relative|fixed` positioned elements, and the default value is for `position` is `static`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some max `height`/`width`, so just write some CSS to `#logo`

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px; /* your maximum in width */
    height: 100px; /* your maximum in height */
    overflow: hidden; /* just to make sure there is nothing leaking your DIV */
}
```