# Elements not overlapping with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, positioning, margin

In my navigation I have a protruding red box. I want that red box to overlap all Divs bellow it. I set a margin for it so it would space it out among the other elements I put in the black box. The problem is that it's margin is also effecting the layout of separate elements' children bellow it. When I add a negative margin to the child elements of the section bellow it does overlap but I want the red box to be on-top. I use z-index and it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my example on Jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/1qsuvhnd/29/

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div id="ribbon"></div>    
</nav>
<div id="context">
    <div class="link"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#context {
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
#context .link {
    float: Left;
    height: 260px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -140px;
    background-color: White;
    z-index:1 !important;
}
nav {
    width: auto;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:99 !important;
    clear:both;
}

nav #ribbon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 50px;
    Width: 65px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index= 99;
}
```

Comment: What's `z-index= 99;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why z-index is not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832741/why-z-index-is-not-working)

Answer (score 5):

To use z-index, you need to specify a `position` (like `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`).

And the last line written is wrong:

```
z-index = 99;
```

The correct way to write it is:

```
z-index: 99;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: http://jsfiddle.net/1qsuvhnd/30/

change the ribbon to position: absolute; and fix the `z-index =` typo :D

Now you don't need that margin hack!!

```
nav #ribbon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 50px;
    Width: 65px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 99;   /* take that equal out and make it a colon */
    position: absolute;  /* position: absolute to the rescue!!!! */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a position CSS rule for the nav div for the z-index to work correctly, like this:

```
nav #ribbon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 50px;
    Width: 65px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:99;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the new jsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/1qsuvhnd/54/