# Can't get ng2-bootstrap modal to show up on top of the bs-modal-backdrop

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I've got an issue using ng2-bootstrap's modals. I'm doing the whole viewContainerRef hack mentioned [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals).
I'm making a modal in a deeply nested component (4 levels deep through routing). I copied the modal code from the above link.
Whenever I try to open it, it opens like this: The bs-modal-backdrop is totally covering the screen, including the modal, preventing me from interacting with it. Any idea why this is happening?[image]

Comment: not sure check z-index of the modal

Comment: So, I did that, and the modal's Z index is... 1050 where the backdrops is 1040

Comment: That's strange. Have u checked position property of the modal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work

Comment: The same happened to me. Have you found a solution? I noticed it happens when I launch it from a nav bar of my app.

Comment: No idea, sorry... I don't even work for that same company anymore so I can't reference the code to figure out what I did

Answer (score 2):

It's a specific situation with a z-index. At least one of the parent components created a stacking context with a z-index less than backdrop z-index 1040. And now all HTML elements will be stacked in it's context.

That's why a backdrop overlaps a modal no matter what z-index a modal has.

To solve the issue:

1. Create a modal in the same context as backdrop so z-index will work. Somewhere outside app header component.
2. Raise parent component z-index so it will be higher than backdrop's 1040.

It's fully described [here](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Comment: Not sure whether (2) raising parent components z-index will help. I suppose then the backdrop won't be visible and/or won't catch click events outside the modal dialog.

Comment: Why not? I remember at least it's visible. Though I won't recommend spoiling bootstrap theme that much. As I understand header stacking context has it's own z-index relative to parent context and if it's bigger than a backdrop than it's perfectly ok. Please note I'm speaking about header z-index, not modal z-index.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me though it's not optimal:

Implement `onShow()` and `onHide()` events like this for modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade"
     bsModal #uploadModal="bs-modal"
     [config]="{backdrop:'static'}"
     tabindex="-1"
     (onShow)="handler('onShow', $event)"
     (onHide)="handler('onHide', $event)"
     role="dialog"
     aria-hidden="true">
```

Then define handler like so:

```
private handler(type: string, event: any) {

    if (this.containerId) {

      let elem:Element = document.getElementById(this.containerId);

      if (!elem)
        return;

      switch (type) {

        case 'onShow':
          elem.classList.add('modal-front');
          break;
        case 'onHide':
          elem.classList.remove('modal-front');
          break;
      }

    }
  }
```

Pass in containerId via some mechanism such as `openModal()`.
Finally, add globally scoped class modal-front that just sets a high z-index.