# SVGs rendering on top of everything

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, google-visualization, material-ui

http://courtstatpack.com is the website where we're encountering this issue.... it's on the date selection on the left-hand side in the options panel.

Both Google Charts and Material Icons are rendering on top of the date picker (https://github.com/nickeljew/react-month-picker) as shown below...?? We've changed date pickers and the same thing still happens. Any clue why?

[image]

z-index doesn't change anything either, as the date picker doesn't seem to care what its z-index is.

Comment: check this --> [The `z-index` property only works on elements with a `position` value other than `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9191845/5090771)

Comment: check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## THE PROBLEM

The problem is the `div` with class `Settings-settings-1316548938` which looks like this:

```
.Settings-settings-1316548938 {
    position: fixed;
}
```

`position: fixed;` creates a [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) which wraps the new [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) that `.month-picker` is trying to create (using `position: relative` and `z-index: 99999999`).

Since there are not more [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) than:

- `.MuiAppBar-positionFixed-2227438490`
- `.Settings-settings-1316548938`
- `.month-picker`

and `.month-picker` is an inner [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) from `.Settings-settings-1316548938` this is causing the problem.

## THE SOLUTION

Easy:

```
.Settings-settings-1316548938 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99; // or any other positive number
}
```

**Why?**

Because `position: fixed;` creates a new [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) but without the `z-index` property, elements are stacked in order of occurrence.So the svg elements come after than the date picker element and that's why you need to specify the `z-index` on your `Settings-settings-1316548938` class.

Also you must understand what I mean when I talk about [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). So follow the link and read the article.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer and explanation!! That took care of it.