# stacking context on table element(head and body)

Tags: css, z-index

I was stuck with one CSS stacking context issue, I simplified it to following simple case.

A simple table as following code, I translated header in order to achieve scrolling effect, while the header was always covered by those translated td cells.

I have read several articles, including that famous one `"What No One Told You About Z-Index"`, and try to add both *translate* and *z-index* css properties on `thead` and `tbody`, and I *'guess'* they should be in the same stacking context, so *z-index* will work, while I failed, does the failure due to `table` has some special constraints on stacking context? The only solution I can find now is switching `thead` and `tbody` position in the html by putting `thead` after `tbody` tag.

Full Case is [here](https://codepen.io/llwanghong/pen/XaMgzZ).

```css
.m-table {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e6eaf9;
  background: #fafbff;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.m-table th,
.m-table td {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #effff0;
}

.m-table th {
  background: #e6eaf9;
}

.m-table thead {
  transform: translateY(25px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

td label.u-angle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #79c5ff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<table class="m-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Algorithm Factor</th>
      <th>Links</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>$1,326</td>
      <td>
        <label class="u-angle"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Detail</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Each element to use z-index needs to have css "position" propety set on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work

Comment: I had already tried to add both translate and z-index css properties on thead and tbody, and thead with larger z-index, and add translate property on table, and the table should be their same sharing stacking context, while the larger z-index setting did not work.

Comment: @HongWang No, you should use the `position` property.

Comment: @MrLister I also try that, it does not work.

Comment: @MrLister, if I replace thead and tbody with div, it works. While for table elements, it fails, so I guess table may have some special constraints on stacking context.

Comment: @HongWang That is certainly a possibility, yes. Tables also respond differently to, say, width properties.