# Z-index not making an element appear above others

Tags: html, css

Here I have a small example of a modal, and I've added z-index: 1000 to a button.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="z-index: 1000" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Why doesn't the button appear above the modal? Or am I totally misunderstanding the z-index property?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G22NNMWCE9PS

P.S. Click "Run" to show the result of the code. Click "Open modal" to open the modal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does z-index not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="z-index: 1051;position: relative;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

The model has z-index: 1050, so the button must have a higher z-index.
By default a button has `position: static;`.
Z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative or position:fixed).

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add the position property..............................

Answer (score 1):

I think Bootstrap already places the modal above `z-index: 1000` (I don't know where exactly), and what you wanna do works with `z-index: 2000;`. The button also needs to be in `position: relative`

Answer (score 1):

Z-index requires positioning. Add `position: relative;` to the button. You will also need to increase the `z-index` value as the modal has `z-index: 1050;` and the button needs a higher value to appear above the modal layer.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are 2 issues here:

1. the modal has a z-index of 1050, you are using 1000.
2. Even if you use,
   say: 1051, it won't work because you need a **positioned** box [*]
   (i.e, the `position` CSS property should be something other than
   `static`.). In this case, you can use `position: relative;` along
   with `z-index: 1050`;

Here's an updated JSBin for reference:

https://jsbin.com/pozilemefa/edit?html,output

[*] Z-index on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index. It says:

> The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a **positioned element** and
>   its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger
>   z-index cover those with a smaller one

Side note: I'd suggest using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org), over W3schools, for as your go to web reference . (I personally use this chrome extension called Hide W3schools to hide all those results from google searches.)