# jQuery .css - z-index not being applied to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am selecting some elements using jQuery and applying CSS like this...

```js
$(".items div").not(".active").css({"color":"green","background":"red","z-index:":"-9"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div class="active">Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
```

The `background` and the `color` both work, but the `z-index` is not being applied.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `z-index` is not applied to elements without a `position`. See [Why does z-index not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9191803/215552)

Comment: Elements don't necessarily accept the `z-index` attribute. There are several ways you can cause them to. The simplest one is probably to add a `position` attribute with a value other than `"static"`. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context for a thorough explanation.)

Comment: what are you expecting to happen with z-index?

Comment: You have multiple typos in your jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't style the element with the `position` property (`relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`), the element will remain in the normal document flow as a block or inline element. Elements in the normal document flow can't be layered with `z-index`.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra colon in your jQuery when setting z-index.

Should be

```
$(".items div").not(".active").css({"color":"green","background":"red","z-index":"-9"});
```

Comment: Have you tried this and found it is now working?

Comment: It applies the z-index properties to the DOM, whereas the original statement wouldn't because the colon caused jQuery to not recognize it as the property. The effect of z-index on these elements is not in the scope of the original question if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Note that you can (when a question is open) click the Copy Snippet to Answer button under the snippet, which would then allow you to show your fix in action. That said, typos are a specific type of problem that is off-topic on Stack Overflow, since it is unlikely to help anyone other than the original poster, so we usually close them for that reason. A couple of things to keep in mind.