# How to overflow-x: visible while overflow-y: scroll

Tags: css, overflow, z-index

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), while talking about overflow, states:

> MDN Note: Setting one axis to visible (the default) while setting the other to a different value results in visible behaving as auto.

So in the following context...

```
overflow-y: scroll/auto
overflow-x: visible
```

...`overflow-x: visible` behaves as `overflow-x: auto`, which in turn seems to behave as `overflow-x: hidden`. Notice in the demo below that half of the orange square is hidden on the Z plane.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#grid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background: black;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 3px;
}

.column:nth-child(1) {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* auto also does not work */
  overflow-x: visible;
  /*
  ** overflow: visible;
  **
  ** uncomment this to allow
  ** overflow on the x plane...
  */
}

.overflow {
  height: 75px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid green 3px;
}

#square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='overflow'></div>
    <div class='overflow'></div>
    <div class='overflow'></div>
    <div id='square'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='column'></div>
</div>
```

**How can I make `overflow-x` truly `visible` while using `overflow-y: scroll`?**

This is what I would like to do...

[image]

Comment: overflow-x: hidden; ?

Comment: @多一点点爱 no, i want to show the orange square on the x-plane, not hide it. i want `overflow-x: visible` to behave like `overflow-x: visible`. i want the orange square to overlap the grid's right column. do you understand?

Comment: @多一点点爱 i uploaded a picture. please look at the picture

Comment: You can’t have something, as far as I know, that scrolls on one axis and shows overflow on another. An element either shows a scrolling view of its contents or it doesn’t.

Comment: @Ry- theres no way to accomplish the overflow on the X plane being visible, while everything on the Y plane is scrolled? not even with some sort of hack approach?

Comment: @Ry- [here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/XWJejPN) that im working on right now which is based on the chinese guys answer. for some reason the `#overflow-wrap { height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll }` does not respect its parent's `height` and even changes the parent's height :/ any idea why thats the case??

Answer (score 2):

@oldboy Is that all right with you？

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#grid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
}

.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid red 3px;
  height: 100%;
}

.column:nth-child(1) {
  /*
  ** overflow: visible;
  **
  ** uncomment this to allow
  ** overflow on the x plane...
  */
}

.overflow {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 75px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid green 3px;
}

#square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  background: orange;
}
.wrap {
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* auto also does not work */
  overflow-x: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class='overflow'></div>
      <div class='overflow'></div>
      <div class='overflow'></div>
      <div id='square'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is precisely what i wanted to do, although i am going to have to take a look at the code to see how you did it before i select it as the answer, but ill give you a vote up for the time being. xiexie <333

Comment: why did you get rid of the grid?

Comment: Or use grid-template-rows: 150px;

Comment: @oldboy I wanted to do that before.but This may not be a good idea. because The left will cover the right

Comment: im just playing around with the concept. if the concept works. ill accept your response as the answer!! i really need/want grid because it allows me to use `gap`

Comment: i figured out the solution. i can simply put `overflow-y: scroll` on `#grid` itself !!

Comment: ahh damn. nevermind. then if one column has overflow, every column scrolls :(

Comment: [here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/XWJejPN) that im working on right now. for some reason the `#overflow-wrap { height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll }` does not respect its parent's `height` and even changes the parent's height :/

Comment: @oldboy Sorry, I can't describe many concepts in English,My English is not very good.

Comment: it is okay. your english is better than my chinese :)

Comment: how is it different from my codepen? is it because `grid-template-rows: 150px` ??

Comment: @oldboy #overflow-wrap { height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll } 100% Don't take effect,or use #overflow-wrap { height: 200px; }

Comment: yeah i noticed that. hmmm the `100% + 30px` and `100% - 30px` is very smart, but it prevents hover/click. it still might be the best option or the least worst compromise

Comment: actually, i think i am going to leave this open hopefully for more answers. just in case

Comment: still pretty damn smart tho