# Put absolute element in front of position-fixed element

Tags: html, css

I simply want to put a button that is positioned as position absolute in front of a div that is positioned as position fixed. This way I want to prevent the button from being disabled when an angular dialog is shown and the shadow overlay of the dialog 'hides' the button. The problem is that when using `position: absolute` setting the `z-index` has no effect. When using `position: relative` at least a negative `z-index` prevents the button from being clicked at all, but it's still visible (don't know if this is expected behavior, I expected it to disappear). But no matter how high the `z-index` value is, it's never on top. The dialog overlay only has a `z-index` of `1000` ;

Comment: Pleas add your code to this question. Without it, we're just guessing what's happening. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, you should read up on [Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help. I already said, that I have position relative/absolute and fixed in use. I know it does not work for static

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't help.