# Make span behind of button text

Tags: html, css

There is 2 spans in a button. One of them for button text and another one for ripple effect when button is hover, but when I hover button ripple span is in front of button text span while I use z-index for both of them.

```css
.login {
    position: relative;
    border: rgb(0, 175, 175) 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
}

.ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    z-index: 0;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    left: -30px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
}

.login:hover .ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(20);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
    z-index: 0;
}

.login:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
        <button class="login">
            <span style="z-index: 10;"> my button </span>
            <div class="ripple"></div>
        </button>
```

Comment: in code snippet

Comment: What is your browser? I'm using Edge

Comment: Note that "the `z-index` CSS property sets the z-order of a [*positioned*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) *element*..." ([z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.login {
    position: relative;
    border: rgb(0, 175, 175) 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    color:#fff;
}

.ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    z-index: 0;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    left: -30px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
}

.login:hover .ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(20);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="login">
    <span style="z-index: 10; position: relative;"> my button </span>
    <div class="ripple"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your code Ehsan jan:

```css
.login span{
    position: relative
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.login {
    position: relative;
    border: rgb(0, 175, 175) 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
}

.login:hover {
    color:#fff;
}

.ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    z-index: 0;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    left: -30px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
}

.login:hover .ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(20);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="login">
    <span style="z-index: 10; position: relative;"> my button </span>
    <div class="ripple"></div>
</button>
```

```css
.login {
    position: relative;
    border: rgb(0, 175, 175) 1px solid;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    color:#fff;
}

.ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    z-index: 0;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    left: -30px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
}

.login:hover .ripple {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(20);
    background-color: rgb(0, 175, 175);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: transform ease 1s;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="login">
    <span style="z-index: 10; position: relative;"> my button </span>
    <div class="ripple"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons why I think you're not getting the expected outcome:

1. `z-index` does not work if you do not set the `position` of your element to anything. check this question for more: [Why does z-index not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191803/why-does-z-index-not-work)
2. the text inside the span is the same color as the ripple, so it's not visible (even if somehow the z-indexing worked)
3. It may or may not have an effect but putting your ripple div after the span is probably covering it up.

Try the following to address these concerns:

Add this to your CSS:

```
.login:hover .button-text{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Modify your button span like so:

```
<button class="login">
     <div class="ripple"></div>
     <span class = "button-text"> my button </span>
</button>
```